# how to use SUMIF along with Union function in SQL

Tags: sql

Please help to create SQL statement SUMIF along with Union function.

I have two table with following details..and i want in table 3 as mentioned below

Table 1

```
EIN     Amt
234223  100
234343  200
234520  150
```

Table 2

```
EIN     Amt
234223  100
234343  300
234520  400
```

I want in query table 3
Table 3

```
EIN     Sumif Amt Total
234223  200
234343  500
234520  550
```

Comment: Sumif is a function of Excel. Why did you tag your question with `sql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what SUMIF is supposed to do, but to me this looks like a simple union with a sum and group by:

```
select ein, sum(amt) as amt_total
from (
  select ein, amt
  from table_1
  union all 
  select ein, amt
  from table_2
) t
group by ein
order by ein;
```